# Order By in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to fetch data from a view. The view contains huge records.
I want to do an order by with the view 
I used order by Col_Name DESC.
It works perfectly fine, but it takes a long time. Time evaluated was 59 seconds,
which is huge as I need to plot the data in a Web Site. A user cannot wait for 59 seconds to see the result.
Can anyone please suggest me how to optimize this?
I googled and found that indexing can be used but how to use it in Views. My tables are already indexed, but that still does not optimize the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the column you order by

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
ADD INDEX col_name_idx (col_name desc)
```

Note that:

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

So maybe in the future a descending index will be used. Currently yo have to life with the ascending one.

If the query is still slow after that you can see where the query needs so much time with `explain`. Run

```
explain select ...
```

and see the output for further optimization potential.

Comment: I used the Explain select to analyze. I have indexed all those columns that it says is required. Is there any way to check if the rows are actually getting indexed or not.

Comment: Can you add the output of `explain` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

try using explain plan

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

and figure out why it is taking so long.